# React Native Error: Can only update a mounted or mounting component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native

I have a RN app where I'm reading in data from Firebase when a component mounts (a 'Favorites' screen), and setting it as the state for the Favorites component to then render.

**But** when I'm on another screen and add an item to the favorites database in firebase, I'm getting a yellow warning of:

*Warning: Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState, replaceState, or forceUpdate on an unmounted component.*

This pops up when I add a new item that would then update the data in `firebase.database().ref('userfavs').child(DeviceID)`. To be clear, the functionality doesn't seem broken and when I console log out the `datalist` array from the state, the new "favorited" item is added on there as expected..

```
class Favorites extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      datalist: []
    };
    this.favsRef = firebase.database().ref('userfavs').child(DeviceID);
  }
  listenForItems(favsRef) {
    favsRef.on('value', (snap) => {
      var items = [];
      snap.forEach((child) => {
         items.push(child.val()
          );
        });
      });
      this.setState({
        datalist: items
         });
     });
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.listenForItems(this.favsRef);
  }

  render() {
    console.log('state datalist:', this.state.datalist);
    ... }}
```

I don't really understand this error, because i've put the `listenForItems` call under `componentWillMount`, so whenever I navigate to the "Favorites" screen and this component loads, it pulls down the most recent data in Firebase.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try componentdidmount?

Comment: @eosterberg yup! error persisted for both componentdidmount and componentwillmount.

Comment: Then I would guess your favorites component has been unmounted, I'd suggest a check if your component is mounted before setting state

Comment: but I'm not setting a state of the `Favorites` component when I add an item to my firebase database... the `.setState` is only called when I call `listenForItems` for when I reopen Favorites screen and the `componentWillMount` is triggered, no?

Comment: Yes but I guess the favorites component is kept in memory even if it's unmounted

Comment: Or even better, (if my assumption above is correct), unregistering favsRef listener on unmount

Comment: @eosterberg - hmm, could you demo what you're speaking of? that way I could also mark it as the answer if it works and give you the credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You´re probably adding a listener that keep your Favorites component in memory after it has unmounted.

According to the docs, there is a `.off` method for detaching the listener:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#off

Solution would be something like:

```
class Favorites extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      datalist: []
    }
    this.favsRef = firebase.database().ref('userfavs').child(DeviceID);
    this.listen = snap => {
      const dataItems = snap.map(child => child.val())
      this.setState({dataItems})        
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() { this.favsRef.on('value', this.listen) }
  componentWillUnmount() { this.favsRef.off('value', this.listen) }
```

Comment: hey @eosterberg -- copying in your code line for line, i got an error running it that `snap.map is not a function. (In 'snap.map(function (child) {return child.val();})', 'snap.map' is not a function`.

Comment: Ok, I was just pseudo coding, then you have to go with the forEach loop